# Component simulator list empty Xcode 9.1 beta

Tags: xcode, components, ios-simulator, beta, xcode9.1-beta

The list of the simulator to download and install is empty.
I deleted Derived cached data but still empty. Is it normal ? is there a workaround to install manually simulators ?

[Image of the empty list simulator in component setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLKym.png)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem on Xcode 9 (non-beta) and was able to work around this issue by installing simulators manually via command line.

I.e. for iOS 10.3.1:

gem install xcode-install

xcversion simulators --install='iOS 10.3.1'